# "QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running" when run from the Windows cmd or IDLE but not from PyCharm?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, freeze, destroy

This is a simplified version of the program implementing PyQt multi-threading with QObject.moveToThread. Basically, I query a webpage on a separate thread and extract the HMTL content.

I get this problem where running the code from IDLE or the Windows command line hangs python. The Windows cmd shows "QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running". However, if I run it from Pycharm, everything works fine.

You can get the .ui file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3IIoC4r3p1CNmpuUm83bWt4QUk)

Any ideas?

```
import requests
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QThread


qtCreatorFile = "window.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


class HttpClient(QObject):

    finished =  pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def retrieve_page(self, url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        self.finished.emit(response.text)


class HtmlGetter(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)       
        self.go_button.clicked.connect(self.query_page)

    def query_page(self):
        http_client = HttpClient()
        temp_thread = QThread()
        http_client.moveToThread(temp_thread)

        temp_thread.started.connect(
        lambda: http_client.retrieve_page("http://www.google.com/"))
        http_client.finished.connect(self.show_html)

        # Terminating thread gracefully.
        http_client.finished.connect(temp_thread.quit)
        http_client.finished.connect(http_client.deleteLater)
        temp_thread.finished.connect(temp_thread.deleteLater)

        temp_thread.start()

    def show_html(self, html_text):
        print(html_text)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = HtmlGetter()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I also get this issue whenever I run multithreaded pyqt programs on Windows, especially if I try to Ctrl-C to kill it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

Both http_client and temp_thread have to be attributes or the HtmlGetter class. I think it's because otherwise python discards them when exiting the function. This is the working code:

```
import requests
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QThread


qtCreatorFile = "window.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


class HttpClient(QObject):

    finished =  pyqtSignal()
    send_text = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def retrieve_page(self, url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        self.send_text.emit(response.text)
        self.finished.emit()


class HtmlGetter(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)       
        self.go_button.clicked.connect(self.query_page)

    def query_page(self):
        self.http_client = HttpClient()
        self.temp_thread = QThread()
        self.http_client.moveToThread(self.temp_thread)

        self.temp_thread.started.connect(
        lambda: self.http_client.retrieve_page("http://www.google.com/"))
        self.http_client.send_text.connect(self.show_html)

        # Terminating thread gracefully.
        self.http_client.finished.connect(self.temp_thread.quit)
        self.http_client.finished.connect(self.http_client.deleteLater)
        self.temp_thread.finished.connect(self.temp_thread.deleteLater)

        self.temp_thread.start()

    def show_html(self, html_text):
        print(html_text)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = HtmlGetter()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```